# Autodesk Construction Cloud Files per project limitation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud

I’m working on one project where I need to transfer bunch of files to Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC) using Forge.
But I’m curious what is limitation of max number files we can upload to particular Project.

I’ve referred below mentioned document for Product tools & limitation
[https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/docs/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/Docs-About-ACC/files/Product-Limitations-html.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

The max files per Folder is 10,000
But There is nothing mentioned about Max files per Project.

Or does it like we can make Number of folders under One Project and each folder has 10,000 files limit?

Please help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no limit to the maximum number of files per project, but has limiations you found in https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/docs/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/Docs-About-ACC/files/Product-Limitations-html.html

- Maximum files per folder: 10,000
- Maximum number of subfolder levels: 25
- Maximum file size: 5TB
- Maximum name length for folders: 255 bytes
- Maximum pages in a PDF file: 2,000
- Maximum number of custom attributes per project: 1,000
- Maximum rows in a files log: 20,000
- Files which can't be downloaded: Data Exchanges